# Jenkins configuration view is messed

Tags: jenkins, java-8, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins version: 2.264
Java Runtime : Open Jdk 1.8.0_272 from https://adoptopenjdk.net/

When I go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System

I see the view is completely messed up. looks like the plugins are scattered all over the page.

Also I could not find Save or Apply button anywhere? How do I save changes on configuration page?

In chrome, dev tools -> console -> I see lot of these errors.

```
> hudson-behavior.js:49 TypeError: e.getAttribute is not a function
>     at findFormParent (hudson-behavior.js:2589)
>     at findNearBy (hudson-behavior.js:275)
>     at Object.nearBy (hudson-behavior.js:327)
>     at hudson-behavior.js:526
>     at hudson-behavior.js:47
>     at prototype.js:853
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at Array.each (prototype.js:852)
>     at HTMLInputElement.e.targetUrl (hudson-behavior.js:525)
>     at registerValidator (hudson-behavior.js:533)
```

Not sure if that causing the layout issue

**UPDTAE 1**
Same issue was also posted on [Jenkins Issue Tracker](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/projects/JENKINS/issues/JENKINS-64072?filter=allopenissues)